# Intuition of LLN's condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent r.v. with finite expectation

If there is a constant $p\in[1,2]$ s.t.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{i=1}^nE|X_i|^p=0$$

then $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-EX_i)\rightarrow_p0$$

If there is a constant $p\in[1,2]$ s.t.
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_i|^p}{i^p}<\infty$$
then $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-EX_i)\rightarrow_{a.s.}0$$

My question is that:

1.Does it means that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_i|^p}{i^p}<\infty$ implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{i=1}^nE|X_i|^p=0$? If so, how to prove it?

I think if $p=1$, then we can directly use Kronecker's lemma to prove it, but what if $p\in(1,2]$?

2. How to understand these conditions? For example,

If $X_1,X_2,...$ be iid r.v.

then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nP(|X_1|>n)=0$$ iff

$$\bar{X}-E(X_1I_{|X_1|\le n})\rightarrow_p 0$$,

so what's the relationship between $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{i=1}^nE|X_i|^p=0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nP(|X_1|>n)=0$? Say if we consider "iid" in the independent WLLN, and let $p=1$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{i=1}^nE|X_i|^p=0$$ becomes
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nE|X_i|=0$$
It doesn't make sense, does it means that "iid WLLN" is not the special case of "independent WLLN" ?

3 Similarly, If $X_1,X_2,...$ be iid r.v.

then $$E(|X_1|)<\infty$$ iff

$$\bar{X}-E(X_1)\rightarrow_{a.s.} 0$$

what's the relationship between $E(|X_1|)<\infty$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_i|^p}{i^p}<\infty$? For example, if we consider "iid" in the independent SLLN and let $p=1$

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_i|^p}{i^p}<\infty$$ implies $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_1|}{i}<\infty$$

compare with $$E|X_1|<\infty$$, let $E|X_1|=c<\infty$

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_1|}{i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{c}{i}=c\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}$$ divergence. So $E|X_1|<\infty$ with iid condition does not imply $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_i|^p}{i^p}<\infty$$

on the other hand, if we have $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_i|^p}{i^p}<\infty$$
can we prove $E|X_1|<\infty$ with iid condition?

Answer (score 0):

1. It cannot be deduced directly that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_i|^p}{i^p}<\infty$ implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{i=1}^nE|X_i|^p=0$ because we do not know a priori whether the results are optimal. For example, the condition $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{i=1}^nE|X_i|^p=0$ could be replaced by something much more restrictive. In order words, we can have $P_1\Rightarrow Q_1$, $P_2\Rightarrow Q_2$ and $Q_1\Rightarrow Q_2$ but it does not mean that $P_1\Rightarrow Q_2$.
   However, that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_i|^p}{i^p}<\infty$ implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{i=1}^nE|X_i|^p=0$ follows but some calculus: let $c_i=E|X_i|^p$ and $s_k=\sum_{i=1}^kc_i$. Using Abel's transformation, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{E|X_i|^p}{i^p}<\infty$ is equivalent to $\sum_k s_k\left(\frac 1{k^p}-\frac 1{(k+1)^p}\right)<\infty$ and we get $\sum_k s_k\frac 1{k^{p+1}}<\infty$. Summing on intervals of the form $[2^n+1,2^{n+1})$ gives $\sum_n s_{2^n}2^{-np}<\infty$ which gives $s_{2^n}2^{-np}\to 0.
2. Indeed, if $p=1$ and the $X_i$ have the same distribution, then both conditions fails. They are actually more appropriated in the case $p>1$, where, as you noticed, the conditions take place provided that $\mathbb E\lvert X_1\rvert^p<\infty$. These conditions are also useful in the non-identically distributed case, when the moment of order $p$ of $X_i$ is even allowed to increase with $i$, but of course not too fast.

Comment: In other word, If we consider same distribution in the "independent WLLN", then we need to satisfy condition $n^{1-p} E(|X_1|^p)\to 0$, it means that $E(|X_1|^p)=o(n^{p-1})$ since $p\in[1,2]$, It means that $E(|X|^p)$ can be infinity. right?  If so, how do we compare with the condition $nP(|X_1|>n)\to 0$ and $\frac{1}{n} \sum E|X_i|\to 0$? say if we all consider with the same distribution, are they the same? If so, why do they have different results? one with indicator, the other do not have indicator function? is it because for " independent WLLN", we assume $EX_i$ exists?

Comment: Also, If we consider the same distribution in "independent SLLN", the condition becomes $E|X_1|^p\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i^p}=c<∞$. It means that $E|X_1|^p=O([\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i^p}]^{-1})$, for a $p∈[1,2]$

Comment: so it means that $E|X_1|^p$ should be relatively small when $p$ is relatively small and $E|X_1|^p$ should be relatively large when $p$ is relatively large, is my understanding correct? If so, It means that in "iid SLLN" we should satisfy a weaker condition then the "independent SLLN" right ? say if we choose p=1.  Then for "independent SLLN" we should have $E|X_1|=O((\infty)^-1=O(0))$,  but in "iid SLLN", we only need $E|X_1|<\infty$ , right?